# Ubuntu 20.04 server installed on usb stick does not see root UUID, Gives up, Drops to Shell

Tags: 20.04, boot-repair

I was running Ubuntu 19.10 Server on two USB sticks for the operating system with four 2 TB ZFS Raid 6 volumes for months before **upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04** when it came out a bit ago.  I restarted once since, but never turned off the power since on my Dell T110 server.  Recently I completely powered it off for about an hour then powered it back on.  **It boots from the USB stick but doesn't see the root partition on the USB stick**, complains that no zfs volumes exist even though `blkid` shows them just fine.  `blkid` does not show the usb stick.

The UUID of the USB stick root doesn't show up anywhere.  **How would I get it booting again?**  I'm convinced at this point that Ubuntu 20 doesn't natively support running root on usb sticks where version 19 was just fine.  It stops at a busybox prompt.

I can mount the same missing partition on a different computer, check it with gparted just fine, and read the information after mounting it just fine.  I've also tried having the usb stick show as a hard drive and a removable drive.

I've tried turning on/off UEFI, on/off TPM Security (usually off), and even pulled half the RAM then swapped for the other two sticks all with the same results.  I've tried booting from the Ubuntu Live CDs, checked the drive which had no errors, even made a gparted copy of the entire USB drive to a regular SATA drive (but couldn't get the ramdisk working.)  I also tried booting from the live server USB to do a reinstall on a fresh drive, but it complains that it cannot locate a live install.  I re-downloaded and remade a separate USB stick twice but cannot get it to boot either.  I've tried the front, back, and inside USB ports with the same results.

Comment: Please clarify your release. Desktop and server releases use a *yy.mm* format for releases, *yy* being used only by snap based specialist releases (usually installed on appliances/devices which are headless without screen/keyboard).  *yy* releases also are only released on even years.  Note: all 2019 releases are now EOL, and no *snap* or *yy* releases were release in 2019  (Since 2016 *yy* releases are different products to *yy.mm* releases)

Comment: Please edit & correct your question. Canonical/Ubuntu has used *yy* for different releases since 2016 to the normal *yy.mm* release, and currently your use of *yy* implies you're on a *snap* only system (not *deb* based *yy.mm* release) with your description text contradicting your used tag

Comment: The fully tested & supported upgrade from 19.04 was to 19.10 (ie. the next release), not 20.04. Yes automated tests occur for all upgrade paths, however that's less than the QA-testing that occurs for the intended 19.04 -> 19.10, then 19.10->20.04 upgraded path. Given you're outside of the intended upgrade path, a re-install maybe best unless you're willing to test it all yourself, and stick to LTS releases if you don't want to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months.  Your question still refers to *snap* only 19? & 20 releases.

Comment: @guiverc The automatic updates did their thing, so I'm sure it went up to 19.10 then 20.04.  I'll update the question.  I'm still trying to bring up this down server.

Comment: @guiverc so I guess the second answer the IT Crowd should give is `Did you try turning it off and then reinstalling it again?`  I ended up having to replace the USB stick with a fresh install on an HDD until we can figure out how to get the USB booting again.  It is odd that it does not show the USB stick as an option under blkid yet the stick mounts on the reinstalled op sys.

Comment: @guiverc I was never able to get Ubuntu 20 running on USB sticks like 19 natively supported. Would you have any links I could follow to restore the USB drivers that natively worked in 19 to 20? I'd like to get my Ubuntu back up and running on USB sticks just like my VMware because SD seems to be so far more reliable than these spindle based HDD drives.

Comment: I have almost no experience with Ubuntu Core releases (and *snap* based*yy* releases) so don't ask me. I only use the standard server & desktop releases that are *year.month* in format and use *deb* packages. There was no *snap* releases in 2019 so there was no Ubuntu Core 19 so I don't know what you mean by *19 natively supported*!  Be specific, the *yy* releases are used in cloud infrastructure as (light) servers but are a different product to the standard *yy.mm* server products (being more capable).